# Unexpected `git config --get core.commentChar` exit code

Tags: git

TL;DR: Why do

```
git config --get core.commentChar
echo $?
```

prints `1`?

---

More context:

With either git `2.14.2.windows.3` on Windows 7 and git `2.7.4` on Ubuntu 16.04, when I run `git config --get core.commentChar` I get the exit error code `1`.

I don't understand this behavior because according to the documentation of [git config](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config):

- The exit code `1` means that `The section or key is invalid`
- but `core.commentChar` is a config documented on this same page

(Also, when I run `git config --get core.editor`, it correctly prints `vim` and has exit code `0`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation really should say "invalid or not set/missing".  In fact, [it *does* say that](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html#_options):

> --get
>
> Get the value for a given key (optionally filtered by a regex matching the value). Returns error code 1 if the key was not found and the last value if multiple key values were found.

Hence, if you have not specifically set `core.commentChar` to something, `git config --get core.commentChar` (a) prints nothing and (b) exits nonzero.  This is distinct from the case where you set it to an empty string, in which case `git config --get` would print nothing but exit with status zero.

Comment: Damned, `Ctrl` + `F` on `exit code` wasn't enough, I should have also looked for `error code`. Thanks!

Comment: The Git documentation always leaves at least a little bit to be desired (consistency, for instance :-) ).